# Displaying Textarea text in a modal popup window

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, modal-dialog

Am using this modal popup code http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial and using the "Simple Modal Window" link.

If there was a textarea box on that page. How would I display the text on the Modal Window?

The code is being used on a php website.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but what you could do is add some code to the modal's click function to grab the textarea's text and then pass it in to the modal itself. It would be something like this, assuming you have a textarea called `myTextArea`:

```
$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //This is the added part:
    //Get the textarea's text
    var taText = $('textarea#myTextArea').val();

    //Example - Now add the text to a span tag inside the modal
    ("#myDiv span").text(taText);

    ...
```

That should hopefully do it.